# Where does Hamelin's Pig Theme come from?

Tags: ni-no-kuni

I understand where Ding Dong Dell's and Al Mamoon's Animal Themes from from given their rulers are a Cat and a Cow but Hamelin's past and current Emperors aren't pigs and everyone only started to wear those pig suits when

> Marcassin was Brokenhearted and lost his Belief

So where does the Pig Theme for Hamelin come from?

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to arqade. It might be on topic here is since NNK is anime style, but the chances of you getting a good answer is a lot higher over there.